# Center-Aligning multiple authors in latex

Tags: author

I have many author of a common document is there any way to center align the authors without making them run out of the page like this

[image]

It is okay if the line breaks

Comment: Without having my crystall ball at hand: do a linebreak by introducing `\\ `, `\tabularnewline` or `\par`. Hard to say based on a *screenshot*. Similar question [How to manage multiple titles in articles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/400602/37907)

Comment: Maybe you are also interested in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage/210280#210280

Comment: Do you use `\author` and `\maketitle`? In this case use `\and` to separate the authors. And please: Always add a minimal but working example to your question.

Comment: If there are just names, and `assddffdff...`  isn't representing an institution, the use of `\and`  will not be very helpful.

Comment: Is there any news here?